# How to get pixel of time value in ChartJs to draw a line?

Tags: chart.js

How to get a pixel of date value? I want to draw a line. But for x axis I have time values. And I am not able to fetch pixel for x because of it. I am trying to use getPixelForValue. But it returns NaN. I need to get exact value to draw a line.

```
const connectorLines = {
    id: 'connectorLines',
    beforeDraw(char, args, options){
        const { ctx, config, scales: { x, y } } = myChart;
            
        // ISSUE HERE -> NaN
        console.log(x.getPixelForValue('2021-11-07T00:23:35'));
        drawArrow(ctx, 128, y.getPixelForValue('C'), 128, y.getPixelForValue('A1') - 4.5, 1, 'rgba(74, 122, 181)');
    }
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    options: {  
         scales: { 
             x: {
                parsing: false,
                position: 'top',
                type: 'time',
                min: '2021-11-07T00:23:20',
                bounds: 'data',
                time: {
                    unit: 'minute'
                }
             } 
         }, 
        indexAxis: 'y',
        grouped: false,
        elements: {
          bar: {
            borderWidth: 2,
          }
        },
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'right',
          }
        }
      },
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: 'S_1',
            data: 
                [
                    {y:'C', x:['2021-11-07T00:23:35', '2021-11-07T00:23:35'], id: 'id1' },
                    {y:'A', x:['2021-11-07T00:23:41', '2021-11-07T00:24:20'], id: 'id2'}, 
                    {y:'A1', x:['2021-11-07T00:23:35', '2021-11-07T00:23:41'], id: 'id3'}
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(74, 122, 181)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                  'rgba(193, 193, 193)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderSkipped: true
          }]
        },
        plugins: [ connectorLines ],
};
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so people can help better and spot where you ,made a mistake

Answer (score 2):

Chart.js converts the dates on the x-axis to numbers that represent the time. Therefore, prior to invoke `getPixelForValue`, you also need to convert the specific date to time, using `Date.getTime()` as shown below.

```
const connectorLines = {
    id: 'connectorLines',
    beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
        const xAxis = chart.scales.x;
        const xValue = new Date('2021-11-07T00:23:35').getTime();
        console.log(xAxis.getPixelForValue(xValue));
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: THis is giving type error if my xValue is string. as getPixelForValue accept only number.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use `getTime()`

```
const drawSelectedRange = {
  id: 'drawSelectedRange',
  beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
    if (selectedDate1 && selectedDate2) {
      const {ctx, chartArea: {left, top, width, height}} = chart;
      const xScale = chart.scales["x"]; 
      var xValMin = selectedDate1, xPixelMin = xScale.getPixelForValue(xValMin);
      var xValMax = selectedDate2, xPixelMax = xScale.getPixelForValue(xValMax);
      ctx.save();
       ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(240, 240, 60, 0.5)'; // yellow
       ctx.fillRect(xPixelMin, top, xPixelMax - xPixelMin, height); // x, y, width, height
      ctx.restore();
    }  
  }
};
```